# onClickButtonListener is stating that it is never used

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener, android-button

I'm having an issue with a method i have created in android studio. the statement should open a new activity when a button 
**Breakfast_continental**
is clicked on.

However the error i m getting is that the ***onClickButtonListener*** is never used.
I am not sure why this is happening as there is a statement within the method.

The method is bellow

```
public void onClickButtonListener() {
  button_cont_break = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Breakfast_continental);
    button_cont_break.setOnClickListener(
          new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View views) {
                  Intent Continental = new Intent(Breakfast.this, Continental_breakfast.class);
                  startActivity(Continental);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

and this is the AndroidManifest.xml entry

```
<activity
android:name=".Continental_breakfast"
android:label="@string/title_activity_continental_breakfast__maps" />
```

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get rid of the void onClickbuttonlistener at the top and it should work

Comment: "The method is never used" is a warning, not an error

Comment: @Blackbelt this is being used in a window that was opened in the same way and code is the same. where would I call the `onClickButtonListener();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line in `onCreate` to actually call the method

```
onClickButtonListener();
```

Comment: You could also move all the code in the method to onCreate and delete the method. You may want to rename it more descriptively if you want to keep it, though, like `setupButton` maybe

Comment: all the cade including the public void? yeah i will be renaming it to `Continental_Breakfast`

Comment: Both the findViewById and setOnClickListener lines can be moved to onCreate. That's what John's answer is saying. You don't need to have this method since you can do it all in onCreate.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `public void onClickButtonListener() {` and put `button_cont_break = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Breakfast_continental);` inside `onCreate` method.

```
button_cont_break.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Continental = new Intent(Breakfast.this, Continental_breakfast.class);
            startActivity(Continental);      
            }
        });
```

Comment: This threw back some issues with the `setOnClickListener` for some reason it wouldn't build and just threw back errors. But I have resolved the issue now, Thanks Anyways.